# Paragraph not expanding parent container / image caption with flexible width according to image

Tags: html, css

I need to know how a paragraph does not influence the
width of the parent container **in CSS only**.
I the image width is not fix!

```css
.parent {
  border: thin solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent js-image-container">
  
<img class="js-image" src="http://dummyimage.com/200/000000/fff" alt="dummy" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  
</div>
```

The result should be like in acontainer with a fixed width,
that the paragraph always has the width of the image.

Greetings
Kaito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use fixed width to container and paragraph will not take auto width

```
    .parent {
     border: thin solid #000;
     width : 200px
    }
```